# Web API - NotFound helper no ModelStateDictionary overload

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

All the helpers have an overload that includes the ModelState. For example

```
return Conflict({YourModelState}),    
return BadRequest({YourModelState});
```

Why for God's sake the return NotFound helper doesn't have one?

Comment: Looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.ok?view=aspnetcore-2.1) i cannot find your ModelState Ok overload.

Comment: @JeroenHeier my mistake, seems that only errors have this overload

Comment: Exactly. Both `Conflict` and `BadRequest` take `ModelState` because *those are errors caused by the state of the model*. A 404 is not a "model state" type of error. Why do you think you need to return `ModelState` with it?